# Trouble having properly inherit default attribute value in SpaCy's PhraseMatcher

Tags: python, inheritance, spacy

SpaCy's PhraseMatcher let's you find phrases in texts that match patterns that you added.
For example:

```
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import PhraseMatcher
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

pattern = 'arthur Dent'

doc = nlp("The only person for whom the house was in any way special was Arthur Dent")

# Standard phrase matcher gives a matching result:

phrase_matcher = PhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LOWER")
phrase_matcher.add(pattern, [nlp(pattern)])

phrase_matcher(doc)
```

This returns a list with one match, as expected,
because the attribute value `attr = "LOWER"` ensures that matching is not case sensitive.

For reasons (adding functionality to add patterns from files) I want to make my own phrase matcher, but I run into the following issue.
I define my phrase matcher as follows:

```
# Inherited phrase matcher, however, gives no matching result:

class MyPhraseMatcher(PhraseMatcher):
    def __init__(self, vocab, attr="ORTH"):
        super().__init__(vocab, attr)
        self.attr = attr

my_phrase_matcher = MyPhraseMatcher(nlp.vocab, attr="LOWER")
my_phrase_matcher.add(pattern, [nlp(pattern)])

my_phrase_matcher(doc)
```

This, however, returns no matches, i.e., an empty list,
when I was expecting the same case insensitive outcome as with the standard PhraseMatcher.
Changing the default value of `attr` to `LOWER` doesn't seem to change this.
Can anyone say what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: If I copy and paste your two code blocks together and print the output of your last line I get a match - are you sure the code you posted doesn't work? Separately, you shouldn't set an attribute for the parent class to use, it's already doing that in init and it transforms the input a little. Also if you have trouble with it, it might be easier to make a class that contains a PhraseMatcher rather than inheriting - look at the EntityRuler. Also check the Matcher docs again, you can read patterns from files. https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching/#entityruler-files

Comment: @polm23 That's interesting, because I just checked again and with me it doesn't. But good to know that it works with you, I'll try to figure out why with me it doesn't. Thanks also for what you said about setting attribute for the parent class. That makes sense, I hadn't thought that through enough.